# Excel 3D Flat Map

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, 3d

I am trying to display some data on the flat version of the 3D map. But unfortunately the map cuts off down the middle of the pacific ocean so half my data is on one end of the map and the rest on the other end. Ideally I would like the map to zoom in on South East Asia and the Pacific Islands. But it seems I would need to include the entire world to show my data. Is there somewhere I can only zoom into the countries I need? 
[image]

Comment: I've never used that feature, but what is the nature of the map image (built-in or an image you can manipulate)?  If you can manipulate the image, think of it as a cylinder that was split in the Pacific .  Split it down the Atlantic and join the Pacific edges.  Then your target area will be in the middle, and you could even trim the sides.

Comment: Yeah. Thanks. I agree. I was hoping not to have to do that cutting and pasting by hand. if there was some automatic way to do it. I was also hoping that the map would be connected to Powerpoint but it looks like it will be a copy paste thing so your solutions works.